# Netbook screen not recovering after Hibernate mode

Tags: ubuntu, hibernate, ubuntu-11.04

Hello I am running the Netbook edition for Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal. Recently whenever I open the lid after hibernation the screen does not turn on. The netbook seems to be running but I am not getting any output or whatsoever, I believe it is a software issue since the lcd is functioning correctly, is there any fix for this ?

Comment: Did it come with Ubuntu?

Comment: no it did not come with ubuntu, it came with windows xp

Answer (score 0):

I will post this conditionally until you answer the question I left above.

If yes, does it have a BIOS update? If no, it just might not work right: I have a laptop that was not designed to run Windows 7, and I have a couple of quirks that I have not been able to resolve because they are not trying to fix them (by updating the BIOS) for an unsupported OS.